# Need to understand this line of Java using the ? conditional operator

Tags: java, syntax, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm currently working on a project and came across a couple lines of code like this:

```
List<Map<Sring, ? super Serializable>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, ? super Serializable>>();
```

This syntax is completely new to me, and I'm having a hard time coming up with any search results on the `?` conditional operator other than the typical `if/else` replacement.

Comment: Voilá http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `? super Serializable` means any type that can hold a reference to a Serializable object. In this particular case, this means either `Map<String,Serializable>` or `Map<String,Object>`.

Frequently this notation is used for recipients of data, following the acronym **PECS**: "producer extends, consumer super".

Comment: It's `super` not `extends`.

Comment: Mistyped the example syntax itself! Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`? super Serializable` means any type `>= Serializable` i.e any type which can capture `Serializable` and any of its supertypes. It indicates the lower bounding class of a generic element.

In your case, it will be a Map of `String` and any class implementing `Serializable` or `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, in this case a ? would mean "anything". So basically it is saying that it is a List of Maps, each of which maps a String to any object that has Serializable as its base class. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: In the context of this application, your answer sounds spot on.  It's basically mapping DataSets in order to pivot the data.

Comment: `super` , so it is "anything that is a supertype of Serializable". Not a *sub* type ...

Comment: The maps must be to Serializable or any of its supertypes - Object. In this case, ? is limited to Serializable or Object, not "anything".